# How to hide the default type constructor in golang?

Tags: go

The reason I have this question is that I often make mistakes that I forgot to specify a value to a struct's field, then the compiler is fine, but the zero value causes bugs.

Here is an example. Say I have a type `Foo` defined like this in a package:

```
package types

type Foo struct {
  RequiredField1 string
  RequiredField2 string
}
```

It is exposed and has 2 fields that I'd like both of them to be specified when the `Foo` struct is created.

Then I can import and use it in my main function like this:

```
package main

import (
  "github.com/foo/bar/types"
)

func main() {
  f := &Foo{ 
    RequiredField1: "fff",
  }
  fmt.Printf("f.RequiredField2: %v", f.RequiredField2)
}
```

This causes a bug because I forgot to specify `RequiredField2` which is required. And I often make this kind of bugs :p

Now, in order to leverage the compile and prevent this mistake, I made a constructor function for `Foo` and asks for the required values.

```
func NewFoo(field1 string, field2 string) *Foo {
  return &Foo{Field1: field1, Field2: field2}
}
```

So that if I forgot to pass `field2`, the compiler won't compile my code:

```
func main() {
    f := NewFoo("foo")
    fmt.Printf("f.Field2: %v", f.Field2)
}
```

The build will fail:

```
./prog.go:18:13: not enough arguments in call to NewFoo
    have (string)
    want (string, string)
```

Now the question is: how to stop the foreign callers (callers from other namespaces) from calling the default constructor of `Foo`, that is `&Foo`, and force them to use the `NewFoo`?

If I can, then I'm safe since NewFoo is the only way to create the `Foo` type and the compiler helps me ensure all fields are present when calling it.

Comment: You can't. Remember, in Go, one of the key rules of thumb is to **make zero values usable**. A `Foo{}` with no fields specified shouldn't just implode; if it does, that is a defect in the design of `Foo`. Take a look at the standard library; it's full of good examples of how to make a good type in Go.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can avoid this problem by making Foo type unexported.

You can make an interface that is Exported and has all the methods that Foo type performs.

Example:-

```
type Foo interface{
DoSomething()
}

type foo struct{
RequiredField1 string
RequiredField2 string
}

func NewFoo(requiredField1 string,requiredField2 string)*foo{
return &foo{
RequiredField1:requiredField1,
RequiredField2:requiredField2,
}
}

func (f *foo)DoSomething(){
// your implementation
}
```

In this way all the caller will be able to access it but cannot create foo without NewFoo function.

Answer (score 3):

> How to hide the default type constructor in golang?

You **cannot** for an exported type.

Get used to it, it is not a problem in real life.

(For unexported types, just provide a `func NewUnexportedType(...) unexportedType`. )

Comment: It is actually a very common problem, because we often need to change the type definition, like adding more fields, and then forgot to update the caller somewhere to specify the missing value, end up causing a bug.

Comment: Whenever I see a `&Foo{ RequireField1: "fff" }`, I'm very nervous, because I don't know if this includes all the required fields.

Comment: @LeoZhang, if you add a field to a struct type in a way that breaks your stuff when it has the zero value, then you've made a breaking change. Don't Do That(tm). Instead add a new type. See ["The import compatibility rule"](https://blog.golang.org/versioning-proposal). But really the overarching rule is that of useful zero values.

Comment: Thanks for the answers.

Answer (score 2):

> [Effective Go](https://golang.org/doc/effective_go.html)
>
> it's helpful to arrange when designing your data structures that the
>   zero value of each type can be used without further initialization.

---

> we often need to change the type definition, like adding more fields

That is why you should make the zero value for struct fields significant. The behavior is by design. For example, it is used to maintain the Go 1 compatibility guarantee.